# How to pass a value validated in Webform to the User's profile page?

Tags: users, webforms

There are hundreds of users on my Drupal 7 website. I don't want to manually enter the birthday value for each user in their profile. Hence why I created a webform where the user puts the user's birthday.

This value should then after validation by the current user be stored permanently in the user's profile where I created an empty birthday field.

How do I pass the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the "[Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules)" module, you should be able to have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module react on an event like "Webform submitted". So create a custom rule using this Rules Event, and then add the required Rules Actions. Here is a blueprint of these Rules Actions:

- <kbd>Fetch Entity by id</kbd>, of type user, using the `uid` of the user who submitted the form (= current user).
- <kbd>Set a data value</kbd>, for the field of the user's profile where you want to save that birthday, where the value is the birthday entered in the form.
- Possibly (not 100% sure) you may also want to add <kbd>Save entity</kbd>, to actually save that field in the profile.

#### Make it right before you make it better ...

But what about a user submitting the same form again, with a different value for birthday? If you don't want that to happen, you might want to add the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module like so:

- Flag a user after submitting the form (using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)), using some *global* flag.
- Improve the 1st rule above, to add a Rules Condition to verify that the user has not been flagged yet.

PS: This answer applies to D7 ...

Comment: Thanks. This is a well round answer and it exactly suited my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the Webform and update the user fields. You need to use form_alter hook for that. Added some sample code you can modify as per your need.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id)
    {
        if($form_id == 'webform_id')
        {
         $form['#validate'][] = 'hook_form_validate'; //function name
         $form['#submit'][] = 'hook_form_submit'; //function name
        }
    }

function hook_form_validate($form,&$form_state){
        // validate you dob field
}

function hook_form_submit($form,&$form_state){
    global $user;
    $account = user_load($user->uid);
          $edit = array();
        if(!empty($form_state['input']['submitted']['first_name'])){
            $edit['field_dob'] = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['input']['submitted']['dob']))); 
       }
        user_save($account, $edit);
    }
```

You can also take a look on [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module.